# What is the most performant way to concatenate a string with a separator

Tags: javascript, algorithm, string-concatenation

Suppose I need to implement a simple `join` function that takes an array and returns a concatenated string of elements separated by a separator. **Kind of what built-in method `Array.prototype.join` does**. All implementations I've seen result in one redundant separator at the beginning or at the end and hence there is a need to trim the string.

For example, I can do it like this:

```
let s = "";
for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) s += sep + arr[i];
// redundant separator at the beginning, need to remove it
s = s.substr(1);
```

Or like this:

```
let s = "";
for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) s += arr[i] + sep;
// redundant separator at the end, need to remove it
s = s.slice(0, -1);
```

Is there a better approach that doesn't produce redundant separator? Import that implementation should efficiently handle all cases like empty array etc.

One way I can think of is to put an `if` statement inside the loop that checks if it's the first/last element and doesn't add a separator in that case, but that seems to be inefficient. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a built-in method of arrays: `arr.join(sep)`

Comment: @slebetman, I know, I mentioned it in the question, but I'm not asking about built-in methods

Comment: *"Kind of what built-in method Array.prototype.join does."* - Kind of? *Exactly* what the built-in method does, no? Are you asking just out of curiosity, or do you actually want to use this instead of `.join()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn, out of curiosity, I used `kind of` wording because I assumed `.join` does some type conversions under the hood which I didn't want to focus on here

Comment: @nnnnnn, what about recursive approach I showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47196375/2545680)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let s = arr[0] || "";
for (let i=1; i < arr.length; i++) s += sep + arr[i];
```

Add the first element, start looping at the second, adding the separator in front.

As you point out in your question, you could use a condition to only append the separator when needed, removing the need to get rid of the redundant one. The problem is, it might be correct if you are joining two or three values, but having to test in every loop iteration will get costly with big arrays.

Comment: `let s = arr[0] || "";` to allow for an empty array?

Answer (score 2):

For the first element, you could check for the length of the array and take the stringed value or an empty string.

Then loop as *Salketer* in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47195888/1447675) is doing:

```
let s = arr.length && arr[0].toString() || '';
for (let i=1; i < arr.length; i++) s += sep + arr[i];
```

Comment: thanks, what about recursive approach I showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47196375/2545680)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define it yourself you can iterate till to the `length- 1`. After the loop you can add the last item only without separator.

Example

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let sep = '-';

function customJoin(array, separator) {

   if(array.length === 0) {
      return '';
   }

   let s = '';
   let length = array.length;

   for (let i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
      s += arr[i] + separator;
   }

   return s + arr[length - 1];
}

console.log(customJoin(arr, sep));
```

Comment: thanks, but what if an array is empty? it will require additional `if` before `arr[length-1]`

Comment: At the start you can do your checking. Return what you want in the `if` statement or throw an error

Comment: The performance effect for one `if` you and your app can't detect. It will last some nanoseconds

Comment: Do we really need the check for length there? I think it will pass the empty string.

Comment: See the last line, if array is empty it will concatenate with `undefined`

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com anyway you need one condition for checking the length

Comment: @SurenSrapyan, thanks, what about recursive approach I showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47196375/2545680)?

Comment: If thinking about recursion, you need to forget about performance comparing with the iteration approach. Iteration approach uses less memory and have more performance

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce:

```
function join(arr, sep){
  if (!arr.length)
    return '';

  return arr.reduce((a,b) => a + sep + b);
}

console.log(join([1,2],'^'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is using recursion:

```
function join(a, separator) {
    if (a.length === 0) return '';

    function concat(a, n) {
        return n > 0 ? concat(a, n - 1) + separator + a[n] : a[n];
    }
    return concat(a, a.length - 1);
}
```

One limitation is that it can't handle large strings of tens of thousands character because of call stack size restrictions.

Comment: Given your question mentioned efficiency I'd think recursion is the opposite of what you'd want, considering the overhead of all the function calls.

Comment: @nnnnnn, thanks, but I'm wondering if I transform it into tail-call position so it can be tail call optimized will it still be behind the alternative `for` loop soltuions? I guess I just like the elegance of this solution compared to extra `if's` in other solutions.

Comment: If you're now shooting for elegance ahead of performance that kind of changes the question, but in any case Salketer and Nina's solutions don't have `if`'s. You can run performance tests at https://jsperf.com/ or elsewhere. Also, your function doesn't handle the empty array case mentioned in the question.